# USB thermal receipt printer driver only accomodates wrong size

Tags: printing, windows-10, driver

I've got a mobile POS thermal receipt printer connected via USB (or bluetooth). I've installed a driver for it, but it only allows printing in defined paper sizes of width 48mm. I need 72mm. Anything I send to the printer prints out as 48mm, so doesn't fill the page/roll.

Think the driver is for a 52mm machine. It's from AliExpress so no actual meaningful branding in sight as many "brands" of it available. All I have is "MP80C1" as the model and the printing width as 72mm (80mm diameter roll)

[Here's the printer](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005709234990.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.0.0.364dLPFuLPFuvm&gps-id=pcDetailTopMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.40050.354490.0&scm_id=1007.40050.354490.0&scm-url=1007.40050.354490.0&pvid=9827920d-71a4-4854-bf4e-301712333fd4&_t=gps-id:pcDetailTopMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.40050.354490.0,pvid:9827920d-71a4-4854-bf4e-301712333fd4,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238110%231995&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21GBP%2172.60%2131.94%21%21%21627.46%21%21%40211b801816976551041592776eb73d%2112000034081221032%21rec%21UK%211759367480%21)
[The link they provide](http://www.weinprinter.com/products_detail.aspx?ProductsID=126&ProductsCateId=74&CurrCateID=74&CateID=74) is for a driver for a narrower print width

When I print to it using a bluetooth printer app it prints fine.

When I use InDesign it prints fine.

The system print dialogue only allows the wrong width.

Found some other random driver but can't get it to recognise my machine.

It has a lot of setup options though and I have a bluetooth mac address for the machine.

This is [the other random driver](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X0G2AqXVingDMLSZ-BxwdridgD3kfhB4) I found from a [similar product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Thermal-Receipt-Auto-Cutter-Ethernet-Commands/dp/B08X2WS2M1)'s amazon description. Obviously I don't know the makers of this, so maybe open sandboxed.

It allows you to change a lot of things using the set printer settings application so I wonder if I can use any of those to let it recognise this as the printer and change the width, but not seen any obvious ways yet.

I wonder if there are any other similar "multi-drivers" that would let me specify 72mm print width.

I have to use this for a big exhibition thing tomorrow so really need to find a way to print the right size!
Many thanks